# Using jQuery to iterate through options in select element

Tags: jquery, html-select, each

I've already seen other examples here on SO but none of them fit my problem.

I have a function that receives a `select` element, and I need it to spit out a JSON formatted string.

Example:

```
foo = buildOptionStructure($('.select-test'));

// Returns string of JSON formatted option data from select
// options in element.
function buildOptionStructure(selectElement) {
    options = "[";
    selectElement.find('option').each(function(option, i) {
        console.log(this); // Return my html in console.
        console.log(option); // Return a zero based index!
        console.log("I VALUE: " + option); // Returns same zero based index!
        options += "{";
        options += "name:'" + option.text() + "'";
        options += "},";
    });
    options += "]"

    return options;
}
```

I just need to build a string out of the options in the given select element. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing a quote in that code.  You also aren't returning anything from your function.

Comment: @james: I edited the question with the missing quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function buildOptionStructure(selectElement) {
    var options = [];
    selectElement.find('option').each(function(k,v) {
        options.push({name: $(this).val()});        
    });
    return options
}

var foo = buildOptionStructure($('.select-test'));

console.log(foo);
```

To get the JSON string, you can use `JSON.stringify(foo)`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kLyeh/1/)

Comment: Nice.  He needs a json string though... how do you get the array into a json string?

Comment: I understand.  I was suggesting you edit the question for the OP's benefit, not mine...

Comment: I added it to my answer as well. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the index when you attempt to use `option.text()` To access the text of the element, use this:

```
    options += "name:'" + $(this).text() + "'";
```